# Click on tablerow should open a fancybox

Tags: jquery, triggers, fancybox, element

I try to open a fancybox triggered by a click anywhere on a table row. After click on a row, I achieve this message in the Firebug console:

> too much recursion
>   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js
>   Line 2925

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="allItems">
    <tr class="itemRow">
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com" class="foo">foo</a></td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="itemRow">
        <td><a href="http://www.bing.com" class="foo">bar</a></td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var itemRow = $('#allItems tr.itemRow');

itemRow.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).find('.foo').trigger('click');
});


$('.foo').fancybox({
    'href' : $(this).attr('href'),
    'width'             : '100%',
    'height'            : '100%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

A live example you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/svebal/zQ8FZ/

Comment: works fine for my browser, no errors whatsover and a lovely fancybox.

Comment: When you're clicking on "some data" or "another data" too? O.O

Comment: Well no, see my answer to make it work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.trigger() is pretty unreliable on several browsers/jquery plugins. You want to do:

```
var itemRow = $('#allItems tr.itemRow');

itemRow.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox({
        'href': $(this).find('.foo').attr('href'),
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the only script you need is this:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
    $.fancybox({
            'href' : this.href,
            'width'             : '100%',
            'height'            : '100%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Bad Idea! :) It should possible to click on the WHOLE table row.
The link inside the first cell I (or the fancybox) only need for the href-attribute.

Here is a better example of that, what I want do: http://jsfiddle.net/svebal/DWEmU/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I overlooked the fact that you wanted to click anywhere on the cell and not the link only. My bad. Luckily you got a good answer to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the lightbox after clicking any td on the tr you must change this line:

```
 $(this).find('.foo').trigger('click');
```

to this

```
 $(this).next().find('.foo').trigger('click');
```

this finds the element which class is foo under the next element